# JSR Validation @Pattern allowing null values

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jackson-databind

When I annotate a field with  @Pattern

```
@Pattern(regexp="someRegexp")
public String name;
```

If the JSON contains this field, with value as **null**, then I expect this regex to fail and thus invalid.

if the JSON does NOT contain this field, then it is fine for the validation to pass.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 year old question, but for the sake of those who stumble onto this question like myself, the only option I can think of is, to use @NotNull in conjunction with @Pattern. Use the pattern to handle the empty string.

Answer (score -1):

To Strings, I usually use @NotBlank for not empty strings, but im not sure at 100% that it doesnt allow null entries, but, in this case, use @NotNull annotation.

Edit: I was looking for an example and I got this from an old project:

```java
@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Pattern(regexp = "somePattern")
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}
```

As you can see, I use NotNull and NotBlank even though I have a pattern there.

Comment: No, @NotBlank just checks if the trimmed length is > 0, if the string is not null. https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank . My requirement is, that the JSR Validation should fail, if the field is present in JSON with value null. If the field is absent, then it should pass. the value, if present, must confirm to the regex.

Comment: Where are you checking if the Strings is null?

Comment: NotBlank already checks null. it's redundant to use NotNull